# Sharepoint list: Update item if it exists or create a new item without flow or any code

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to update item if it exists in a sharepoint list or create a new item, without flow or any coding since I do not have access to those 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for your answer is "No".

We cannot update item automatically without flow or code.